# Visual Studio 2010 lingering tool windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have two strange issues in VS 2010.

At home, every time I start Visual Studio I have the error window that is active although I close it every time when I quit. I do not have that problem at work.

At work, I have a lingering Server tool window that is open when starting the application, but once VS is fully started it disappear, yet this isn't where the tool window is located when I open it manually.

I don't care much about the second problem, but I would very much like to know if there's a setting to not make the error window open all the time.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these steps:

- Close the error window
- Export this setting to a file on your disk (Tools>Import/Export Settings)
- Import this settings file and see if the error window comes up again on startup

Comment: And then I can look up the setting and maybe identify what's wrong if that doesn't work. Will give that a shot.

Comment: Moving to VS 2012 RC obviously fixed my problem as it reset all settings.